# Date formatting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on JS code below in which `.text(data.format_data.nextRechargeDate);` returns the date in the following format: `"2019-02-09T05:00:00"`

**Javascript Code:**

```
this.$modal.find('.next-date').text(data.format_data.nextRechargeDate);
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the JS code above so that it returns the data format in the following way:

```
January 11, 2019
```

At this moment, as mentioned above it returns in the following format `"2019-02-09T05:00:00"`

Comment: if you're using Node try moment.js

Comment: I am using moment.js @Guywhotypesfast How can I use moment.js code here ?

Comment: documentation shows this: `moment().format('LL'); // returns January 11, 2019`

Answer (score 1):

With [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) you can format the string date to the desired format as follows:

```js
const formattedDate = moment("2019-02-09T05:00:00").format('MMMM DD, YYYY');

console.log(formattedDate); // "February 09, 2019"
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.23.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) method to format your date `"2019-02-09T05:00:00"` like this:

```js
var x = new Date("2019-02-09T05:00:00"); //replace this with your retrieved modal text

var options = { month: 'long', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };

x = x.toLocaleDateString("en-us", options);

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are after, as the environment you are using is not exactly clear, but I hope this will help you get into the right direction

```js
document.getElementById('next-date').value = moment().format().substr(0, 10);//(new Date()).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="next-date">
<button onclick="alert(moment(new Date(document.getElementById('next-date').value)).format('MMMM DD, YYYY'))">test</button>
```